# I can't get my data back, The Post function is working fine, tested with postman

Tags: javascript, api, backend

I can't get my data, Post function is working fine I'm using Postman for testing it. When I put `localhost:3000/api/names/2`, I get this error

> Can not GET /api/names/2

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
var cors =require('cors')
app.use(express.json()); app.use(cors())
const names = []

app.get('/api/names/', (req, res) => {
res.send(names);

} );

app.post('/api/names', (req, res) => {
     const name = {
         id: names.length,
         name :req.body.name

     };
     names.push(name);
     res.send(name); 
 });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('port 3000'));
```

Comment: Either use localhost:3000/api/names/ or localhost:3000/api/names/:id

Comment: it returns the whole array @AndrewRayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To GET

```
app.get('/api/names/:id', (req, res) => { res.send(names.filter(x => x.id == req.params.id););
```

Comment: its working but returns the whole array when i put 'localhost:3000/api/names/id:2' or localhost:3000/api/names/2

Comment: @MalikShafi need to filter. I have updated my coding.